# Calculate volumes using triple integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to calculate these two volumes using triple integrals:

volume of $A = \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 : {x^2\over a^2} + {y^2\over b^2} \leq z \leq 1 \}$

volume of $B = \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq a^2, x^2+y^2-ax \geq 0,x^2+y^2+ax \geq 0 \}$

So I want to calculate the integral of the function 1 over A but I'm having a hard time finding the limits of integration. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In B): What is $\large r$ ?. If it a parameter ?. In that case, please use another letter $\large\left(~\mbox{for example:}\ {\large a > 0}~\right)$. Otherwise, it can be confused with $\large x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = r^{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{{\rm e}^{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}$

- $\color{#ff0000}{\left.\Large A\right)}$
  \begin{align}
  \int_{{x^{2} \over a^{2}}\ +\ {y^{2} \over b^{2}}\ \leq\ z\ \leq\ 1}\dd^{3}\vec{r}
  &=
  \verts{ab}\int_{x^{2}\ +\ y^{2}\ \leq\ z\ \leq\ 1}\dd^{3}\vec{r}
  =
  \verts{ab}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dd\theta\int_{0}^{1}\dd\rho\,\rho\int_{\rho^{2}}^{1}\dd z
  \\[3mm]&=
  2\pi\,\verts{ab}\int_{0}^{1}\dd\rho\,\rho\pars{1 - \rho^{2}}
  =
  2\pi\pars{{1 \over 2} - {1 \over 4}}\,\verts{ab}
  =
  \color{#ff0000}{\Large{\pi \over 2}\,\verts{ab}}
  \end{align}

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing here...

Comment: @Nikki I changed variables $x$ and $y$. It's like $x' = x/\left\vert a\right\vert$ and $y' = y/\left\vert b\right\vert$ albeit I reuse, for simplicity, the same letters: $x/\left\vert a\right\vert \to x$, $y/\left\vert b\right\vert \to y$. That switches the ellipse like expression $\left(x/a\right)^{2} + \left(y/b\right)^{2}$ to a more friendly $x^{2} + y^{2}$ circle like expression. In cylindrical coordinates, your region definition becomes $\rho^{2} \leq z \leq 1$ since $x^{2} + y^{2} = \rho^{2}$. Then, it becomes clear how to choose the integration limits.

Comment: Ok, now i get it, thanks.

Comment: @Nikki Fine. You're welcome.

Comment: Would you mind helping me with the other one too? I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Nikki I can try later. It's too late right now: ( 5 a.m. ).

Answer (score 2):

Volume A is an elliptic paraboloid with its "vertex" at the origin, truncated by the plane $ \ z \ = \ 1 \ $ .  Because it has a symmetry axis along the $ \ z-$ axis, it is actually convenient to integrate using a single variable, since every "slice" parallel to the $ \ xy-$ plane is an ellipse, the area of which has a simple dependence upon $ \ z \ $ .

[image]

If it is insisted upon that the volume be found using triple integration, we can work out some of the integration limits from the equation for the surface.  At any specific value $ \ z \ \ge \ 0 \ $ , we have

$$ \ z \ = \ {x^2\over a^2} + {y^2\over b^2} \ \Rightarrow \ y \ = \ \pm  \ b \sqrt{z} \ \cdot \ \sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{a^2 z}}  \ \ . $$

The elliptical cross-section at a particular $ \ z \ $ has a "semi-horizontal" axis of length $ \ a \ \sqrt{z} \ $ and a "semi-vertical" axis $ \ b \ \sqrt{z} \ $ .  Because of the four-fold symmetry of these cross-sections, we can just integrate over the first quadrant and multiply the result by four.  The volume integral in Cartesian coordinates is then

$$ V_A \ = \ 4 \ \int_0^1 \int_0^{a \sqrt{z}} \int_0^{b \sqrt{z} \ \cdot \ \sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{a^2 z}}} \ \ dy \ dx \ dz \ \ = \ \ 4b \ \int_0^1 \int_0^{a \sqrt{z}} \ \sqrt{z} \ \cdot \ \sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{a^2 z}} \ \  dx \ dz  $$

[the integration over $ \ y \ $ simply gives us $ \ y \ $ evaluated at the upper integration limit]

$$ = \ \ 4b \ \int_0^1  \ \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{z} \ \left[ \ a \sqrt{z} \ \arcsin \left(\frac{x}{a \sqrt{z}} \right) \ + \ \frac{1}{a \sqrt{z}}  \cdot  x \ \sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{a^2 z}} \ \right]\vert_0^{a \sqrt{z}} \ \   dz  $$

[the integration over $ \ x \ $ is accomplished using a sine-substitution: the anti-derivative appears in many applications, so I won't derive it here]

$$ = \ \ 2b \ \int_0^1  \  \sqrt{z} \ \left( \ a \sqrt{z} \ \arcsin \ 1 \ + \ 0 \ - \ 0 \ + \ 0  \ \right) \ \   dz \ \ = \ \ 2ab \ \int_0^1  \ z \ \cdot \ \frac{\pi}{2}  \ \   dz  $$

[pulling the constants together shows us that each "horizontal slice" is indeed an ellipse with the expected area $ \ \pi \ ab \ z \ $ ]

$$ = \ \pi \ ab \ \left( \ \frac{1}{2} z^2 \ \right) \vert_0^1 \ = \ \frac{\pi \ ab}{2} \ \ , $$

confirming **Felix Marin**'s result using cylindrical coordinates.  Since the "height" of the volume is one unit, the volume expression gives the appearance of only having two dimensions, but in fact has three.

$$ \ \ $$

Volume B is that of a sphere of radius $ \ a \ $ centered on the origin, less the volume of two circular cylinders of *diameter* $ \ a \ $ with their symmetry axes parallel to the $ \ z-$ axis, these axes passing through $ \ ( \ \frac{a}{2} , 0, 0 \ ) \ $ and $ \ ( \ -\frac{a}{2} , 0, 0 \ ) \ $ , respectively.  (We want the volume "inside the sphere, but outside of the cylinders".)

[image]

What we will compute is the volume of the portion of the sphere within the two cylinders, and subtract the result from the familiar expression for the volume of a sphere.  The symmetry of this geometrical arrangement is *eight-fold*, so we can consider integration in the first octant.  In the $ \ xy-$ plane, we will integrate over a semi-circle of radius $ \ \frac{a}{2} \ $ with its center at $ \ ( \ \frac{a}{2} , 0 \ ) $ , and integrate in the $ \ z-$ direction from that plane "upward" to the surface of the sphere.

In rectangular coordinates, the "bounding function" for the semi-circle is given by

$$ \ ( x - \frac{a}{2} )^2 \ + \ y^2 \ = \ \left( \frac{a}{2} \right)^2 \ \Rightarrow \ y \ = \ \sqrt{ax \ - \ x^2} \ \ , $$

and that for the spherical surface is

$$ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ + \ z^2 \ = \ a^2 \ \Rightarrow \ z \ = \ \sqrt{a^2 \ - \ x^2 \ - \ y^2} \ \ . $$

The integral for the volume of the sphere contained by the cylinder is therefore

$$ 8 \ \int_0^a \int_0^{\sqrt{ax \ - \ x^2}} \int_0^{\sqrt{a^2 \ - \ x^2 \ - \ y^2}} \ \ dz \ dy \ dx \ \ .  $$

However, this soon produces a rather daunting calculation.  It proves to be much easier to work in cylindrical coordinates; setting up the integral can be done using our Cartesian-coordinate integral as a guide.  The integration in $ \ z \ $ now "runs" from $ \ 0 \ $ to $ \ \sqrt{a^2 \ - \ r^2 } \ $ .  The semi-circle expressed in polar coordinates is half of the "one-petal rosette" $ \ r \ = \ a \ \cos \ \theta \ $ , with the angle "running" from $ \ 0 \ $ to $ \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ $ .  So we will instead calculate

$$ 8 \ \int_0^{\pi / 2} \int_0^{a \ \cos \ \theta} \int_0^{\sqrt{a^2 \ - \ r^2 }} \ \ dz \ r \ dr \ d\theta \ \ = \ \ 8 \ \int_0^{\pi / 2} \int_0^{a \ \cos \ \theta} \ r \ \sqrt{a^2 \ - \ r^2 } \  \ dr \ d\theta  $$

$$ = \ \ 8 \ \int_0^{\pi / 2}  \ \left[ \ -\frac{1}{3}  \cdot   \ (a^2 \ - \ r^2)^{3/2} \ \right] \vert_0^{a \ \cos \ \theta} \ \ d\theta $$

$$ = \ \ \frac{8}{3} \ \int_0^{\pi / 2}  \  a^3 \ - \ ( \ a^2 \ - \ a^2 \ \cos^2 \ \theta \ )^{3/2} \ \ d\theta  \ \ =  \ \ \frac{8}{3} a^3 \ \int_0^{\pi / 2}  \  1 \ -  \   \sin^3 \ \theta  \ \ d\theta $$

$$ =   \ \frac{8}{3} a^3 \  \left[ \ \theta \ \vert_0^{\pi / 2} \ -  \  \left( \ u \ - \ \frac{1}{3} u^3 \ \right) \vert_{-1}^0  \ \right] $$

[using, in the second integrand term, the substitution $ \ du \ = \ \sin \ \theta \ d\theta \ , \ u \ = \ -\cos \ \theta \ $ ]

$$ =   \ \frac{8}{3} a^3 \  \left[ \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ -  \  \left( \ 0 \ - \ 0 \ - \ [\ -1 \ ] \ + \ [ \ -\frac{1}{3} \ ] \ \right)   \ \right] $$

$$ =   \ \frac{8}{3} a^3 \  \left( \ \frac{\pi}{2}  \ -  \   \frac{2}{3}  \ \right) \ = \  \frac{4 \pi}{3} a^3 \ -  \  \frac{16}{9} a^3  \ \ .  $$

Since this is the volume of the portion of the sphere *within* the cylinders, it is to be removed from the total volume of the sphere, which is $ \  \frac{4 \pi}{3} a^3 \ $ .  Hence, the volume of region B is

$$ V_B \ = \ \frac{16}{9} a^3  \ \ .  $$